# How to modify value in array by position at aggregation framework

Tags: arrays, mongodb, aggregation-framework

Let's say a have a simple document:

```
{
   array: ["a", "b", "c", "d"]
}
```

How to modify the *second* value in **aggregation**?

With `update` it is very simple:

```
db.collection.updateOne({},
   { $set: { "array.1": "B" } }
)
```

gives:

```
{
   array: ["a", "B", "c", "d"]
}
```

In aggregation framework you can use this one:

```
db.collection.aggregate([
   {
      $set: {
         "array": {
            $map: {
               input: "$array",
               in: {
                  $cond: {
                     if: { $eq: [{ $indexOfArray: ["$array", "$$this"] }, 1] },
                     then: "B",
                     else: "$$this"
                  }
               }
            }
         }
      }
   }
])
```

However, this fails when the array is not a Set, i.e. values are not unique like this one

```
{
   array: ["a", "b", "c", "b"]
}
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can loop over the [**`$size`**](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/size/)(length) of the array using [**`$range`**](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/range/) and then get the index of the element and can change the value of the index element to whatever you want.

```
db.collection.aggregate([
  { "$project": {
    "array": {
      "$map": {
        "input": { "$range": [0, { "$size": "$array" }] },
        "in": {
          "$cond": [
            { "$eq": ["$$this", 1] },
            "B",
            { "$arrayElemAt": ["$array", "$$this"] }
          ]
        }
      }
    }
  }}
])
```

[***MongoPlayground***](https://mongoplayground.net/p/7uDvL-J_9K5)

Answer (score 1):

Another solution is to $unwind your array with includeArrayIndex and preserveNullAndEmptyArrays, set value with condition, then group. But beware, although it can be useful in some situations, it can consume more server resources in some cases.

```
db.collection.aggregate([
  {
    $unwind: {
      path: "$array",
      includeArrayIndex: "index",
      preserveNullAndEmptyArrays: true
    }
  },
  {
    $addFields: {
      array: {
        $cond: {
          if: {
            $eq: [
              "$index",
              1
            ]
          },
          then: "B",
          else: "$array"
        }
      }
    }
  },
  {
    $group: {
      _id: "$_id",
      array: {
        $push: "$array"
      }
    }
  }
])
```

you can test [here](https://mongoplayground.net/p/Pmmobx7OoYu)

Comment: all this to modify 1 element in array :(

Answer (score 0):

I found a solution which requires less coding:

```
db.coll.aggregate([
   {
      $set: {
         array: {
            $function: {
               body: function (array, i, val) { array[i] = val; return array; },
               args: ["$array", 1, "B"],
               lang: "js"
            }
         }
      }
   }
])
```

When you need to update nested array, then the difference is even bigger. Let's assume a nested array as this:

```
{
   action: [
      { task: ['a', 'b', 'c', 'd'] },
      { task: ['aa', 'bb', 'cc', 'dd'] },
      { task: ['aaa', 'bbb', 'ccc', 'ddd'] }
   ]
}
```

It can be updated simply with

```
db.collection.aggregate([
   {
      $set: {
         action: {
            $function: {
               body: function (action, a, t, val) { action[a].task[t] = val; return action; },
               args: ["$action", 1, 2, "new CC"],
               lang: "js"
            }
         }
      }
   }
])
```

compared to

```
let arrayIndex = 1
let taskIndex = 2
db.collection.aggregate([
     {
        $set: {
           action: {
              $map: {
                 input: { $range: [0, { $size: "$action" }] },
                 as: "a",
                 in: {
                    $cond: {
                       if: { $eq: ["$$a", arrayIndex] },
                       then: {
                          $let: {
                             vars: { action: { $arrayElemAt: ["$action", "$$a"] } },
                             in: {
                                $mergeObjects: ["$$action", {
                                   task: {
                                      $map: {
                                         input: { $range: [0, { $size: "$$action.task" }] },
                                         as: "t",
                                         in: {
                                            $cond: {
                                               if: { $eq: ["$$t", taskIndex] },
                                               then: "new CC",
                                               else: { $arrayElemAt: ["$$action.task", "$$t"] }
                                            }
                                         }
                                      }
                                   }
                                }]
                             }
                          }
                       },
                       else: { $arrayElemAt: ["$action", "$$a"] }
                    }
                 }
              }
           }
        }
     }
 ])
```